# jQuery Select All Textboxes In Each Row Where Checkbox is Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have view that contains a table with the following structure:

```
<table id="mappings">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb-master" /> Structure</th>
            <th width="15%">Excel Column</th>
            <th width="15%">Excel Row Start</th>
            <th width="15%">Excel Row End</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-1" value="1" /> Item 1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="col-1" value="A" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rstart-1" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rend-1" value="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-2" value="2" /> Item 2</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="col-2" value="B" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rstart-2" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rend-2" value="20" /></td>
        </tr>
          .
          .
          .
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-n" value="n" /> Item n</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="col-n" value="Z" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rstart-n" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="rend-n" value="20" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where `ItemId` is the value contained in the checkbox, and the `id` of each input is appended with the `Id` of the current item. How can I iterate through the table above with jQuery and create a JSON array containing the values of the textboxes in each row where the checkboxes `checked` value is set to true?

I would like the JSON object to look like this (if possible):

```
[
    { "ItemId": "1", "ExcelColumn": "A", "ExcelRowStart": "5", "ExcelRowEnd": "20" },
    { "ItemId": "2", "ExcelColumn": "B", "ExcelRowStart": "5", "ExcelRowEnd": "20" },
        .
        .
        .
    { "ItemId": "n", "ExcelColumn": "Z", "ExcelRowStart": "5", "ExcelRowEnd": "20" }
]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON Object".  Do you want a javascript object or a String containing the JSON representation of that object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add class for the input, then coding can be simpler

```
 <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-1" value="1" class="ItemId" /> Item 1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="col-1" value="A" class="ExcelColumn"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rstart-1" value="5" class="ExcelRowStart" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rend-1" value="20" class="ExcelRowEnd" /></td>
 </tr>

var result = [];
$("tbody :checked").each(function(){
   var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
   var item = {};
   $("input", tr).each(function(){
       item[$(this).attr("class")] = $(this).val();
   });
   result.push(item);
});
```

check this at  http://jsfiddle.net/mxELP/4/

Comment: thanks for the suguestion for classes, that sounds like a great idea, I will try implementing that.

Comment: when I try implementing this, It returns a large collection of `[object Object], [object Object], ..., [object Object]` when I print it out in an `alert(result)`.

Comment: What it gives you is a json array. Try alert(JSON.stringify(result))

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
$("#mappings tr input:checkbox:checked")
    .closest("tr").find("input:text").css({ "border" : "1px solid red" });
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xgSpp/

To serialize the selection to JSON you can simply call `serializeArray`. The only catch is that you have to provide names for the elements.

```
var result = $("#mappings tr input:checkbox:checked").closest("tr").find("input:text").serializeArray();
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: @JamesJohnson thank you, this works great to select the textboxes and looks very elegant. How would I use this to extract the values into the JSON array though?

Comment: @shuniar: If you add names to the inputs, you can just call serializeArray on the selection to get the JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/rmwSY/

Mind that I think you made a typo on `<td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-2" value="1" />`. Shouldn't this be `value="2"`?

Comment: yes thank you, I will correct that in my sample and take a look at your jsfiddle.